# How to keep socket.io client in frontend code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, client-server

I am just learning webdev and want to try to make a multiplayer game using Express and socket.io

I can make a server with socket.io in it which listens. That part works fine.

However when I try to connect a client, this only works if I let the HTML file with the following in it be **served** by the server like follows:

Server code:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const http = require('http')
const server = http.createServer(app)
const { Server } = require('socket.io')
const io = new Server(server)

const port = 3000

io.on('connection', (sock) => {
    console.log('client connected')
})

// This seems to be necessary, but I don't want it to be!!!
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html')
})

server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

This index.html has the following at the bottom:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>const socket = io()</script>
```

However I want to keep all my frontend code seperate from the server. I made a seperate repository for the frontend and backend. I want the frontend to contain all the UI logic and use only data calls (AJAX) to get Json data from the server. So I want to put this index.html file in my frontend code only.

Yet if I do this the connection doesn't work.

I can start the server fine.
I open index.html from WebStorm which also creates a server for this which I configured to also listen to port 3000

Yet it cannot find /socket.io/socket.io.js and I get the following error in the console.
It also doesn't work if WebStorm runs on a different port.

```
The resource from “http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).
```

How can I keep this html in my client repo only and still work with socket.io, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple servers listening on the same port. Run the servers on different ports and either:

- Have a reverse proxy forwarding requests to your Socket.io server (which needs [special handling](https://socket.io/docs/v4/reverse-proxy/)) and your front end server *or*
- Put an absolute URL in the script src and [configure CORS](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/).

Comment: It worked!!! All I needed to do was add the following to the server:

```const io = new Server(server, { cors: { origin: "http://localhost:8080" }})```

And the following to the client:

```<script src='http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
<script>
var socket = io('http://localhost:3000');
</script>```

Thank you so much!